# What are possible casue of broken websites when old cookies are present?

Tags: cookies

I have more than 10 years of experience as a web dev. Mostly do Front-End stuff, but I also do backend for personal projects. I never had this kind of bug in my app that required clearing the cookies to fix the issue. And this happens a lot with a commercial website that I use, if something doesn't work the support says to clear the cookies and it often fixes the issue.

So my question is: what are the possible causes of old cookies breaking the website? I can't imagine how old cookies can break new versions of the site (or web app).

Did your project had this problem? Do you know what was the root cause?

The only thing that came into my mind is broken legacy code that was not deleted.

Comment: How come this is not focused? It's about one thing.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most common issues are related to authentication.

You hit a webpage, its checks for an auth cookie and if there isn't one you go through the auth flow and get a cookie

But! now you are logged in, javascript makes millions of calls back and forth using the auth token from the cookie in a single page app style.

The token expires, or the cookie is from a previous version, or you are assigned more rights etc and suddenly these calls start failing.

SPA frameworks and javascript as a whole isn't great with handling this situation. all the individual "ajax" calls are failing, but nothing is taking the overall responsibility to refresh the page or update the token.

Comment: So the problem is with sessions? Will JWT solve the issue?

Comment: no, jwt has the same issue, you need to deal with refresh tokens in every fetch call. Which is totally doable, but people dont